# Сортировка List<> по значению поля

Tags: java

*Всем привет!*

У меня вопрос касательно того, как можно красиво и наиболее правильно оформить сортировку `List<>` по значению.

Какого-то определённого термина обозначения данной сортировки я не нашёл, поэтому назвал её *"по значению" (если кто-то считает, что можно навзвать более выраженно, то милости просим).*

Итак, в чём суть:

Есть класс `Product`

```
@Data
public class Product {

    /**
     * Тип продукта
     */
    private ProductType productType;

    /**
     * Доступность продукта (продукт может быть временно заблокирован и не доступен)
     */
    private Boolean isAvailable;
    
    private enum ProductType {
        NEW,
        OLD,
        REMOVED,
        UNUSED,
        EXCLUSIVE
    }

}
```

Предположим, что данный класс хранится в Базе Данных и когда я его вытаскиваю от туда, то получаю `List<Product>`, а затем я должен вернуть его на `FRONTEND` в отсортированном виде.

**Заказчик выдвинул требования.**
Упорядоченность в списке должна быть следующая:

1. ProductType == EXCLUSIVE **И** isAvailable=true
2. ProductType == NEW **И** isAvailable=true
3. ProductType == OLD **И** isAvailable=true
4. ProductType == UNUSED **И** isAvailable=true
5. ProductType == REMOVED **И** isAvailable=true
6. Все оставшиеся продукты у которых isAvailable=false

Вопрос насущный: как правильно организовать такого рода сортировку.

Если вы хотите знать смысл такого рода сортировки, то это не должно быть вашей заботой. ВАМ выдали ВОТ ТАКИЕ ТРЕБОВАНИЯ и нужно сделать так, как требуют.

У меня была идея сделать что-то вроде такого, а именно модернизировать класс `Product`, добавив метод для определения приоритета, а потом использовать `Comparator`.

```
@Data
public class Product {

    /**
     * Тип продукта
     */
    private ProductType productType;

    /**
     * Доступность продукта (продукт может быть временно заблокирован и не доступен)
     */
    private Boolean isAvailable;

    public int getPriority() {
        if (productType.equals(ProductType.EXCLUSIVE) && BooleanUtils.isTrue(isAvailable)) {
            return 1;
        } else if (productType.equals(ProductType.NEW) && BooleanUtils.isTrue(isAvailable)) {
            return 2;
        } else if (productType.equals(ProductType.OLD) && BooleanUtils.isTrue(isAvailable)) {
            return 3;
        } else if (productType.equals(ProductType.UNUSED) && BooleanUtils.isTrue(isAvailable)) {
            return 4;
        } else if (productType.equals(ProductType.REMOVED) && BooleanUtils.isTrue(isAvailable)) {
            return 5;
        }
        
        return 6;
    }
    
    private enum ProductType {
        NEW,
        OLD,
        REMOVED,
        UNUSED,
        EXCLUSIVE
    }

}
```

**Использование**

```
private static Comparator<Product> PRODUCT_SORT = Comparator.comparing(Product::getPriority)
        .reversed();
```

Но возможно есть более лаконичные способы, поэтому прошу всех желающих предложить свой вариант.

Comment: "сортировку по значению" - то, что вы привели в качестве примера - это не сортировка по значению. Какая логика, что у вас сначала идет 98, потом 99, а потом 86 ?

Comment: Не совсем ясна суть вопроса. Пишите, что хотите отсортировать, но так же хотите чтобы список был в произвольном порядке.

Comment: Как понять "непонятна логика"? Её вообще нет, мне нужно задавать приоритет сортировки исходя из значения строки. Порядок на первый взгляд выглядит произвольным, но давайте будет считать, что число 98 должно быть первым, а число 99 вторым по каким-то ВАЖНЫМ причинам. Просто я не стал описывать смысл такого порядка, так как считаю это не относится к теме. Порядок не произвольный. В описание вопроса внёс правку

Comment: Если внести в эти значения контекст, то смысл будет понятен. Допустим вместо чисел у нас будет погода. В таком случае я бы хотел, чтобы первым в списке шли элементы, где погода была "Гроза", потом "Дождь без грозы", потом "Туманная", а в конце "Солнечная". То есть просто важно задать порядок сортировки не по-возрастанию и убыванию, а исходя из значения элемента. Определить приоритет, так сказать.

Comment: Если вы расширяете контекст, как в вашем примере с грозой и прочим, то вы сортируете не _строки_, а некоторые _объекты_ или хотя бы кортежи (record): `record Weather(WeatherType weather, String num){}`, и тогда можно использовать компаратор по некоему свойству, и в конце при необходимости берете требуемое свойство `num()` и преобразуете `List<Weather> -> List<String>`

Comment: А что если не будет никакого лишнего свойства? Я имею ввиду у объекта Weather будет лишь одно поле String, в которым будет текстом прописано состояние погоды {"Солнечная", "Гроза"} и т.д.. Правильно сделать конечно enum какой-нибудь и задать каждому состоянию свою цифру, но у меня такой возможности нет. Как правильно выстроить сортировку при наличии только поля String?

Comment: Так вы определитесь, что у вас в строках записано: "Солнечная" / "Гроза" или какие-то коды "96", "46".

Comment: Что будет записано в строках это не важно. Человек с ником IR42 ниже привел вариант решения задачи. Можете прочитать этот вариант решений и будет понятно. Меня интересуют все возможные варианты такого решения. Я просто люблю чистый код и мне интересно

Comment: Ваш вопрос непонятен (абсурден) по сути, о чём вам написали в первых комментариях, поскольку в нём отсутствует логика: _хочу отсортировать числа по значению в порядке, определённом в **постороннем** контексте_.  Предложенное решение фактически сводится к использованию индексов и является _очень_ неэффективным `(O(N^2 * log(N)))`.

Comment: Давайте ради Вас перепишу задачу с контекстом)

Comment: @NowhereMan готово, можете прочитать

Comment: @NowhereMan только не нужно писать, что я написал кардинально другие вещи. Мне нужна была сама идея и я не хотел как то усложнять формулировку. Любую из идей решения предыдущей формулировки я бы смог понять и применить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Если вы хотите знать смысл такого рода сортировки, то это не должно быть вашей заботой. ВАМ выдали ВОТ ТАКИЕ ТРЕБОВАНИЯ и нужно сделать так, как требуют.

Дело в том, что как раз важно понимать, почему требования такие. В этом случае, в частности, важно такой порядок важен только в этом конкретном сценарии, или он обусловлен порядком "важности" типов продуктов в любом сценарии. Я тут использую слово "важность", но правильней будет использовать то слово, которое используют в данной предметной области.

Реализация будет правильней и лучше, если модель предметной области будет ей соответствовать. А данном случае на практике это означает, что если тип продукта имеет "важность" (или "приоритет") сам по себе независимо от сценария, то имеет смысл это явно выразить в модели, это можно сделать добавив поле в enum:

```
    public int getPriority() {
        return BooleanUtils.isTrue(isAvailable) ? productType.getOrder() : 6;
    }
    
    private enum ProductType {
        NEW(1),
        OLD(2),
        REMOVED(3),
        UNUSED(4),
        EXCLUSIVE(5);

        int order;  // это и есть "важность"

        ProductType(int order) {
            this.order = order;
        }

        int getOrder() {
            return this.order;
        }
    }
```

Если же порядок сортировки зависит от сценария, то тогда, скорее неправильным будет размещать `getPriority` в `Product`. Лучше задать порядок для сценария например так:

```
ImmutableMap<ProductType, Integer> MAIN_PAGE_PRODUCT_ORDER = ImmutableMap.of(
      NEW, 1,
      OLD, 2,
      REMOVED, 3,
      UNUSED, 4,
      EXCLUSIVE, 5
);


private static Comparator<Product> sortBy(ImmutableMap<ProductType, Integer> productTypeOrder) {
   return Comparator.comparing(
           p -> p.isAvailable() ? productTypeOrder.get(p.getProductType()) : 6)
        .reversed();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать массив с нужным порядком элементов и при сортировке сравнивать по индексу

```
var values = List.of("98", "99", "86", "41", "56", "46");
var list = new ArrayList<>(List.of("99", "99", "86", "46", "98", "98", "56", "41", "46"));
list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(values::indexOf));


[98, 98, 99, 99, 86, 41, 56, 46, 46]
```